# Apache cxf + soap anonymous addressing

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, apache-camel, cxf

I am new to Soap addressing and I have to use wsa addressing with Apache cxf + camel.

This is the service endpoint created by apache cxf from wsdl

```
@WebMethod(operationName = "Inventory_SubmitResult", action = "http://htng.org/PWSWG/2010/12/Inventory_SubmitResult")
@Action(input = "http://htng.org/PWSWG/2010/12/Inventory_SubmitResult", output = "http://htng.org/PWSWG/2010/12/Inventory_SubmitResultResponse")
public void inventorySubmitResult(
    @WebParam(partName = "OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRS", mode = WebParam.Mode.INOUT, name = "OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRS", targetNamespace = "http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05")
    javax.xml.ws.Holder<OTAHotelInvCountNotifRS> otaHotelInvCountNotifRS
);
```

Having issues serving request,
In soap request this is the namespace value for wsa in soap2:Header

```
xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
```

Problem I am facing is when ReplyTo header in incoming request has below value

```
 <wsa:ReplyTo>
            <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
 </wsa:ReplyTo>
```

then cxf interceptors is trying to call back the above address and failing with 
'405 Method not allowed' and my functionality does not work.

Error stack trace in the logs

```
2018-10-30 22:13:35,720  WARN org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain:475 - 5bd939df4b105100018a9fcc@:int - [Path:/integration-service/synxis/tenants/101/properties/103] -[Tenant Id: 101] -[Property Id: 103] - Interceptor for {http://synxis.com/Ota2010a/}IOta2010AService#{http://synxis.com/Ota2010a/}Inventory_SubmitResult has thrown exception, unwinding noworg.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Could not send Message.\n        at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:67) ~[cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n  at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.OutgoingChainInterceptor.handleMessage(OutgoingChainInterceptor.java:90) [cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n     at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.resume(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:278) [cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n       at org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.impl.InternalContextUtils$1.run(InternalContextUtils.java:319) [cxf-rt-ws-addr-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n    at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$3.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:421) [cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]\n        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]\n  at org.apache.cxf.workqueue.AutomaticWorkQueueImpl$AWQThreadFactory$1.run(AutomaticWorkQueueImpl.java:346) [cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n      at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_112]\nCaused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '405: Method Not Allowed' when communicating with http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous\n    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.doProcessResponseCode(HTTPConduit.java:1620) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1627) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1572) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n   at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1373) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n       at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:225) ~[cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n        at org.apache.cxf.io.CacheAndWriteOutputStream.postClose(CacheAndWriteOutputStream.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n    at org.apache.cxf.io.CachedOutputStream.close(CachedOutputStream.java:225) ~[cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n        at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56) ~[cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n     at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:673) ~[cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:63) ~[cxf-core-3.2.5.jar:3.2.5]\n  ... 10 common frames omitted\n
```

I tried below things

1. Changing the  namespace value for wsa in soap2:Header like below and
   its working.

   ```
   xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing"
   ```

   2. Changing the reply to address value like below and it's working.

http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous

3. Removing the ReplyTo header is working

But I cannot do all this as request comes from third party.

I tried editing(removing the replyto header/updating the address node value in reply to header) soap headers in the request by putting a interceptor in PRE_LOGICAL phase but it did not work

```
   public class WsaHeaderInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

    public WsaHeaderInterceptor(String replyToUrlTemplate, MessageType messageType) {
        super(Phase.PRE_LOGICAL);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
        //hard-coded for debugging
        Header header = message.getHeaders().remove(1);

                ((Element) (header.getObject())).getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getFirstChild()
                      .setNodeValue("" + "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous");

                ((Element) (header.getObject())).getFirstChild().getNextSibling().getFirstChild()
                     .setTextContent("" + "http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous");

    }
}
```

Spent days on this and could not able to fix, any clues or pointers will really help.

WSDL file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:tns="http://synxis.com/Ota2010a/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" name="OTA2010A" targetNamespace="http://synxis.com/Ota2010a/" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="ota2010AEndpoint_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing />
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xs:schema xmlns:tns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <!--removed types -->
  </wsdl:types>

  <wsdl:message name="InvCountDeliveryResponse">
    <wsdl:part xmlns:q1="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" name="OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRS"
            element="q1:OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRS" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="InvCountDeliveryResponse_Headers">
    <wsdl:part xmlns:q2="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" name="Security" element="q2:Security" />
    <wsdl:part xmlns:q3="http://htng.org/1.3/Header/" name="TimeStamp" element="q3:TimeStamp" />
    <wsdl:part xmlns:q4="http://htng.org/PWSWG/2007/02/AsyncHeaders" name="CorrelationID" element="q4:CorrelationID" />
    <wsdl:part xmlns:q5="http://htng.org/PWSWG/2007/02/AsyncHeaders" name="RelatesToCorrelationID" element="q5:RelatesToCorrelationID" />
    <wsdl:part xmlns:q6="http://htng.org/PWSWG/2007/02/AsyncHeaders" name="ReplyTo" element="q6:ReplyTo" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:message name="InventoryCountResponse">
    <wsdl:part xmlns:q7="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05" name="OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRS" element="q7:OTA_HotelInvCountNotifRS" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="InventoryCountResponse_Headers">
    <wsdl:part xmlns:q8="http://htng.org/1.3/Header/" name="TimeStamp" element="q8:TimeStamp" />
  </wsdl:message>

  <wsdl:portType name="IOta2010A">
    <!-- Adding Inbound for Async Response starts here -->
    <wsdl:operation name="Inventory_SubmitResult">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://htng.org/PWSWG/2010/12/Inventory_SubmitResult" name="InvCountDeliveryResponse" message="tns:InvCountDeliveryResponse" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://htng.org/PWSWG/2010/12/Inventory_SubmitResultResponse" name="InventoryCountResponse" message="tns:InventoryCountResponse" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>

  <wsdl:binding name="ota2010AEndpoint" type="tns:IOta2010A">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#ota2010AEndpoint_policy" />
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Inventory_SubmitResult" >
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://htng.org/PWSWG/2010/12/Inventory_SubmitResult" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input name="InvCountDeliveryResponse">
        <soap12:header message="tns:InvCountDeliveryResponse_Headers" part="Security" use="literal" />
        <soap12:header message="tns:InvCountDeliveryResponse_Headers" part="TimeStamp" use="literal" />
        <soap12:header message="tns:InvCountDeliveryResponse_Headers" part="RelatesToCorrelationID" use="literal" />
        <soap12:header message="tns:InvCountDeliveryResponse_Headers" part="ReplyTo" use="literal" />
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output name="InventoryCountResponse">
        <soap12:header message="tns:InventoryCountResponse_Headers" part="TimeStamp" use="literal" />
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>

  <wsdl:service name="OTA2010A">
      <wsdl:port name="ota2010AEndpoint" binding="tns:ota2010AEndpoint">
         <soap12:address location="https://integcert.synxis.com/Interface/ota2010av2/OTA2010A.svc"/>
         <wsa10:EndpointReference>
            <wsa10:Address>https://integcert.synxis.com/Interface/ota2010av2/OTA2010A.svc</wsa10:Address>
         </wsa10:EndpointReference>
      </wsdl:port>
   </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

Comment: Can you add the wsdl?

Comment: @delephin added wsdl file

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't really answer the question but hopefully this info can be useful:

So the requestor uses the `http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing` namespace but then specifies the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous` URI?

`schemas.xmlsoap.org` namespaces are used for SOAP 1.1. while `www.w3.org"` namespaces are used for SOAP 1.2.

However the [SOAP 1.2 spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-soap/#nsrefs) says that SOAP 1.2 should be backwards compatible.

> WS-Addressing is conformant to the SOAP 1.2 Messaging Framework processing model and is also compatible with SOAP 1.1  for backwards compatibility.

[Here is the spec on SOAP 1.2 anonymous addressing](https://www.w3.org/TR/ws-addr-soap/#anonaddress)

It does look like the `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/role/anonymous` URI is recognized in CXF via the `org.apache.cxf.ws.addressing.VersionTransformer` class.

It seems like the addressing in the request should be valid and should be understood by CXF.